Redirecting from Next.js Landing Page to old ASP e-commerce Cart
I need to redirect a user from our newly build Next.js Landing Page to a client ASP e-commerce Cart.
I'm trying to create a session on the old website, store the session/cookies, make a POST request to their API using those credentials and finally redirect to the old e-commerce cart page.
The only problem is I'm getting CORS error when trying to create the session from the Next.js Landing Page. I can ask them to add the landing page/my dev env. to their allow origins headers, but they're very slow and unresponsive and I would like to get this done fast.
Is there any other way to accomplish this? Will I have to ask them to change their server configuration? Has anyone ever done something similar before?
I'm using Next.js 14 with the App Directory and Route Handler.
